# How to compare two different time in moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have viewed many questions here regarding comparing moment dates but none would resolve my problem. I am comparing two date. The code is below. `params.start` and `params.end` have date strings in them such as `'8:15 PM'`. `Slots[0].slot.forEach` is just because I am iterating over the array in db.

```
if (params.start && params.end) {
  slots[0].slots.forEach((slot) => {
    //slot.start and slot.end are coming from database
    let dbStart = moment(slot.start, "hh:mm A").format("hh:mm A"); //8:15 PM
    let dbEnd = moment(slot.end, "hh:mm A").format("hh:mm A"); //9:00 PM

    //start and end have the data the user has passed
    let start = moment(params.start).format("LT"); //8:30 PM
    let end = moment(params.end).format("LT"); //8:50 PM

    console.log(start, end, dbStart, dbEnd);
    //8:30 PM 8:50 PM 8:15 PM 9:00 PM

    console.log(typeof start, typeof end, typeof dbStart, typeof dbEnd);
    //string string string string

    let status = slot.status;

    if (start >= dbStart && end <= dbEnd)
      //The above condition is not working as expected. 
      //It is not comparing the values 8:30 >= 8:15 and 8:50<= 9:00 should return true 
      //but it is returning false for some reason. 
      temp.push({
        dbStart,
        dbEnd,
        status
      });
  });
}
```

Am I doing the comparison wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/ There are a number of comparison functions listed in the documentation, like `isBefore`, `isAfter`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling the method `.format()` a string will be returned. In your code you will save these strings as the parameters: `dbStart`, `dbEnd`, etc. Which you will then compare, so a.t.m. you are comparing strings, while instead you should be comparing Moment.js objects. So just remove the `.format()` calls, change your code to:

```
if (params.start && params.end) {
  slots[0].slots.forEach((slot) => {
    //slot.start and slot.end are coming from database
    let dbStart = moment(slot.start, "hh:mm A");
    let dbEnd = moment(slot.end, "hh:mm A");

    //start and end have the data the user has passed
    let start = moment(params.start);
    let end = moment(params.end);

    let status = slot.status;

    if (start >= dbStart && end <= dbEnd)
      //The above condition is not working as expected. 
      //It is not comparing the values 8:30 >= 8:15 and 8:50<= 9:00 should return true 
      //but it is returning false for some reason. 
      temp.push({
        dbStart,
        dbEnd,
        status
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: But then this returns me the complete object including the date. The console print this `Moment<2020-09-22T20:30:21+04:00> 
Moment<2020-09-22T21:00:28+04:00> 
Moment<2020-09-22T20:47:00+04:00> 
Moment<2020-09-22T21:07:00+04:00>`

Comment: How to remove the date part?

Comment: When you log it just do: `console.log(start.format("LT"))`. this wil return a string and won't edit the value of `start`.

Comment: The date part doesn't have to be removed, moment.js automatically sets a date when you set a moment object from a timestamp and that date would be today. But this doesn't matter for your code because the if check also compares on time.